# Smoothing active capacitive stylus lines, LG G pad X

Tags: lg, touchscreen, stylus, drawing

No idea if this is the right place to post this, since I don't know if the problem is my OS (android 6.0), stylus (Xiron active capacitive), software, or screen. My stylus makes very jerky/wavy lines, especially when slow and diagonal. However, it works ok with the *passive* capacitive end of it or best just my finger. The only app that seems to smooth this is Bamboo Paper. But, I need to annotate PDFs, which bamboo cannot open. Do i have a faulty pen? Is there better software that I could use? Pics below of finger vs stylus in bamboo and adobe reader.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Long time ago I owned a Note2, whose Stylus had similar issues. Dropping it on a firm hard surface like on carpet with the stylus end hitting the carpet was one solution and that actually helped. It could be opened up easily and the potentiometer adjusted to increase /decrease sensitivity. See if you can do this on your pen or try the tapping on firm surface method repeatedly and see if it helps

Comment: You can try apps specifically meant for pdf like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applikationsprogramvara.sketchonpdfs&hl=en_US) or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgogolin.penandpdf)

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, but sadly hitting the tip didn't help. I tried those two and many others, and the only program that seemed to work ok was INKredible, but it's still just a little jerky/the resolution of the writing is so low to the point of frustration.

Comment: [Xiron lacks pressure sensitivity](https://www.msn.com/en-us/lifestyle/shopping-all/ditch-the-apple-pencil-for-these-top-rated-ipad-styluses/ar-BBZYJTZ) ; maybe this is the reason?

Comment: [Wiki says active pens are expected to detect more than 8000 pressure sensitivity levels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_pen) and if Xiron doesn't have this feature, this could well be the reason for your frustration. On bamboo paper app, you are not seeing this, because it is specifically meant for stylus writing and compensates, resulting in smooth lines unlike a pdf (no proof, but sounds logical to me)